# Apply Getter property returning array at res.locals in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I try to develop a simple flash function for expressjs (please no links to existing libraries, I know them).

One single issue does headache. If i assign req.session.flash to res.locals.messages I want to make it that the array is set to [] if you read it. Background: If a jade template iterate through it, after the iteration it shall be empty, otherwise you see old messages again.

Code so far:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  assert(req.session, 'req.session is required!')

  if (!util.isArray(req.session.flash)) {
    req.session.flash = []
  }

  console.log(req.session.flash)

  res.locals.messages = function() {
    var flash = req.session.flash
    req.session.flash = []
    return flash
  }

  res.flash = function(type, msg) {
    console.log('res.flash')
    req.session.flash.push({
      type: type,
      msg: msg
    })
  }
  next()
})
```

Its gona work, but the problem is I have to execute a function in jade like

```js
for flash in messages()
  .alert.alert-danger
    strong= flash.msg
```

but I want it more like that:

```js
for flash in messages
  .alert.alert-danger
    strong= flash.msg
```

without the ()

Any ideas how to get it works like that?

Edit:

One approach is near to the solution, but not complete yet.

```js
if (!res.locals.messages) {
  Object.defineProperty(res.locals, 'messages', {
    get: function() {
      var flash = req.session.flash
      req.session.flash = []
      console.log('flash in getter', flash)
      return flash
    }
  })
}
```

The prolem is, I get the error

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need a undefined check:

```
Object.defineProperty(res.locals, 'messages', {
    get: function() {
        var flash = req.session.flash || [];
        req.session.flash = []
        console.log('flash in getter', flash)
        return flash
    }
})
```

But in all honesty I would prefer the `messages()` approach. Javascript isn't a land where people will typically expect object attributes to behave as if they were C# attributes with getters/setters and what not. Making messages a function makes this clearer to people reading your code.